# How can I scrub through a video for saving screengrabs frame by frame?

Tags: video-player

Is there a linuxsoftware suitable for this? Unfortunately VLC doesn't let me do that.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/45803/video-players-that-have-frame-by-frame-playback-feature

Comment: `ffplay` `s` steps one frame, but I couldn't find a way to save the screenshot with it

Answer (score 3):

For actual scrubbing through a video, i.e. advancing frame by frame, this *can* be done with vlc. The feature can be accessed by pressing the 'e' key or using the button marked 'Frame by Frame' under View --> Advanced controls, then using the screenshot capabilities of vlc which by default can be activated by using  Shift+s. As far as I can see this will not run *backwards* though.

There are a few other *non-scrubbing* options with MPlayer and FFmpeg. MPlayer is capable of outputting images either automatically or manually from a video clip and perhaps this would be helpful. Have a look here:

[Tip 5: Taking screenshots](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPlayerTips#Tip_5%3a_Taking_screenshots)

FFmpeg has similar capabilities but with vastly more options:

[Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

[How to take multiple screenshots to an image (tile, mosaic)](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20take%20multiple%20screenshots%20to%20an%20image%20%28tile,%20mosaic%29)

But certainly the only genuine scrubbing option, and that forwards only, was with vlc...

Comment: Basically I mean that if I press the right arrow it should give me the next frame, where I could get a still from and so forth.

Comment: OIC, looks like vlc has something like this which by default you can access by pressing the 'e' key or using the button marked 'Frame by Frame' under View --> Advanced controls. As far as I can see this will not run backwards though.

Comment: VLC previous frame feature request https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/10252 and a plugin that does it http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Jump+to+time+(Previous+frame)+v2.1?content=156396 To take the screenshot: right click on image > Video > Take snapshot. Saved to `~/vlcsnap-<date>.png`.

Comment: VLC is very finicky about single stepping though... for instance, I've got some 60fps 1080p video that it just does nothing when I try to single step (but it displays the text like it thinks it did).  I also found a 10+ year old bug reported where sometimes single stepping will cause the player to completely hang due to buffering issues.  Supposedly to be fixed in version 5 (but it's only on version 3 now, wat?)

Answer (score 3):

[SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/) ( `sudo apt install smplayer` ) lets you go forward and back frame-by-frame with the <kbd>.</kbd> (dot) and <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) keys.

Make sure you have "mpv" selected as the "Multimedia engine". It's under Options -> Preferences, at the top of the "General" tab. If you have "mplayer" selected instead, you can step forward frame-by-frame, but not backwards.

In the same Preferences tab, you can enable screenshots, and configure path and filename.

[image: Preferences tab]

The default key for taking a screenshot is <kbd>S</kbd>.

Unfortunaltely, there seems to be no way to display the current frame number (or the timecode) in the player. As far as I know, only Quicktime 7 does that, but it will not be available anymore after MacOS 10.14 (Mojave).

Comment: How is it possible that this does a better job at playing videos sped up than mpv does, when it's using mpv as the engine

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install totem
```

Then use `.` and `,` to move to previous or next frame